# Installed plugins page do not show in wordpress dashboard

Tags: plugins

I have a wordpress single site install. Everything was working fine since I built the site 2 months ago.

Suddenly the plugins page does not show.

I see the plugins and can go to the settings of some of them and I can open the plugins editor for plugins code file.

The only last thing I adjusted on my site was installed Scheme plugin and deactivated Accelerated Mobile Page plugin and kept the AMP plugin.

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer and that is w3-total-cache is doing that. But I am not sure why it does that. I will now look in to why w3-total-cache can disable a lot of things in the dashboard.

If anyone has gone through this and has tips for me please let me know.

thank you,
neha